# count and print total number of empty lines from user input in java

Tags: java, line, counter

I have written a program to count lines and words from user input.

Problem : **I need the program to count lines even if they are empty, while below code doesn't count empty line**.

I have tried using *isEmpty()* method but it doesn't work and I saw a method called *isBlank()* but to use it you need to download a library. Is there any other way to count empty lines?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Counter2{
  public static void main(String[]args){
    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    int words = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
      String line = scan.nextLine();
      arrayList.add(line);
      words += line.split(" ").length;

    }
    System.out.println("lines: " + arrayList.size());
    System.out.println("words: " + words);
    scan.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't very helpful, what issue more exactly do you have?

Comment: Well, would this loop ever stop reading inputs?

Comment: @Kris I will be using this program in linux terminal, it is for an assingment, we are allow to stop  reading input using control + d so there is not problem with that.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the issue is that when my input is an empty line the program doesn't count it, and I need the program to count all lines even if they are empty.

Comment: Are you sure pressing ctrl+d is not a problem, when will the last rows after the loop be executed?

Comment: You should debug  this. It looks fine to me,  but I'm not at my computer now. Specifically, you are adding each line to the list, even the blank ones. Does scanner.nextLine() skip blank lines?

Comment: @NomadMaker That is right, I have found the mistake...
this part of the code  ---while (scan.hasNext())--- should be replaced by ---while (scan.hasNextLine()) ---  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Check your line is null and not empty by :

```
line != null && !"".equals(line.trim())
```

If you don't want to do anything with lines and words and just count them, why don't use two counting variables for this?

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
      String line = scan.nextLine();
      if(line != null && !"".equals(line.trim())) { 
        lineCount++;
        wordCount += line.split(" ").length;
      }
 }

 System.out.println("Lines:" + lineCount);
 System.out.println("Words:" + wordCount);

}
```

Comment: OP wants to count empty lines as well and you are doing the opposite. And what is wrong with using isEmpty?

Comment: @Tran Ho  I just want to count lines and words, this code does it but when input is an empty line it does not count it, and I need the program to count lines even if they are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.in.read` to get all the input from the terminal instead of `Scanner.hasNext()`. The `\n` character is valid on all platform to indicate a new line.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Counter2 {

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        int words = 0;

        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        int n ;
        while ((n = System.in.read()) != -1) {
            if (n=='\n') {
                arrayList.add(line.toString());
                if (!line.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    words += line.toString().split(" ").length;
                }
                line = new StringBuilder();
            } else {
                line.append((char) n);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("lines: " + arrayList.size());
        System.out.println("words: " + words);
    }

}
```

The snippet above does not count new line as word.